# The home page not displayed in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I use chrome browser.
I use this row:

```
 <td><a href = '/'; >Home</a></td>
```

To go back to home page.

For example:

If I have this URL in address bar:

http://localhost:1234/#reportPage

After I press `Home`,I get this URL in address bar:

http://localhost:1234/

The `reportPage` is ID of the div tha has data-role="page".

The address bar is changes but the view not changes(the old view remain in the same place,the view of HTML page not changes).

But if use FF or IE browser it works perfect,when I press `Home` button the address bar changes and also the view changes to the Home page. Any idea why I have problems the the code above in google chrome?

Here my HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="muni">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
    <title>Review</title>
    <link href="css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/rtl/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <script src="scripts/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
            $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController as main">
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>{{vm.config.customer.name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <img style="display: block; margin: 10px auto 30px auto;max-width: 90%; max-height: 90%;" ng-src="{{vm.config.customer.logo}}" alt="{{vm.config.customer.name}}" />
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
                <a href="#reportPage" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tmblocate">Sites Mapping</a>
                <a href="#messages" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tmbmail">Messages</a>
                <a href="#underConstruction" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tmbmap">On Cnostruction</a>
                <a href="#underConstruction" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tmblock">Profile</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="reportPage" ng-controller="reportController">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>{{vm.config.customer.name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div ng-show="stage=='map'">
                <div> 
                    <table class="button-panel">
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="images/mail-sent.png" ng-click="goNextStage()" /></td>
                            <td class="big" ng-style="{'background': 'url('+ report.Photo +') no-repeat center', 'background-size': '200px'}"><img src="images/photo-large.png" ng-click="takePhoto()" /></td>
                            <td><img src="images/home-large.png" ng-click="goPreviousStage()" /></td>
                           <td><a href='/#'>Home</a></td> <----this Home link!!!

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <select id="reportType" ng-model="viewModel.reportType" ng-options="reportType.Text for reportType in reportTypes"></select>
                <div id="addressForm">
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:200px">
                                <input ng-model="search.addressSearch" placeholder="Enter address" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:auto">
                                <button ng-click="searchForAddress()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-search ui-corner-all"></button>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left">
                                <button ng-click="gotoMyLocation()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-location"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="stage=='success'">
                <div>
                    <table class="button-panel">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="big"><img src="images/home-large.png" ng-click="goPreviousStage()" /></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="margin: 20px 10px;">
                    <img src="images/success.png" style="float: right; width: 100px; margin: 5px;" />
                    <h3>Site saved</h3>
                    <p>
                        Saved.<br />
                        Number: <span id="reportId">{{reportId}}</span>
                        <br />
                        Thank you for coorparating
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div ng-show="stage=='error'"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="addressPanel" data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li ng-repeat="address in search.results">
                    <a href ng-click="setAddress(address)">{{address.formatted_address}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="messages" ng-controller="messagesController">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>Masseges</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div>
                <table class="button-panel">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="big"><img src="images/home-large.png" ng-click="goBackPlease()" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <ul id="messageList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li ng-repeat="message in messages | orderBy:'-Date' track by $index">
                    <h2>{{message.Title}}</h2>
                    <p ng-bind-html="message.Body | wrapphones"></p>
                    <p style="text-align: left">{{message.Date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="underConstruction">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>On construction</h2>
            <a href="#" onclick="window.goBackPlease()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all btn-back" style="float: right !important;">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <img style="width: 95%; display: block; margin: 10px auto;" src="images/Under-Construction.gif" alt="Under Construction" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="logPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>LOG</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <ul id="log"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    z
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/ol.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/config.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/filters/wrapphones.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/services/coordinateSerivce.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/services/reportService.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/services/mapService.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/services/pushService.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/controllers/reportController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/controllers/messagesController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the semicolon is there for what?

Comment: Perhaps the full url may work. `<a href="localhost:1234">Home</a>`

Comment: FYI: `http://localhost:1234/#reportPage` and `http://localhost:1234/` is the same page, one URL just has a hash on the end, it doesn't even reload the page to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You basically don't go to another page, or reload it. You stay on the same page, just trying to jump to the top. `#reportPage` takes you to an element with the id `reportPage`, removing the id doesn't necessary mean "scroll to top". As you seem to get to the top of the page, just change it to:

```
<td><a href='/#'>Home</a></td>
```

It'll function correctly, by explicitly taking you to the top.

If it doesn't work still, the suggestion is to set the location to `/` and reload the page with javascript:

```
<td><a href='javascript:location.href="/";location.reload();'>Home</a></td>
```

The `location.reload()` sentence may be excess (for me it does work without it), but as you say you have problems with reloading, you can also try with this sentence.

Comment: I tried but  it's dosen't work, address bar and the view not changes,

Comment: @niceal, but why do I have to reload() the page if I only need to relocate to another div with ID  = home ?

Comment: @Michael "relocate to another div with ID = home" - where did you say it before?? Again, your aim is?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure of all, add this line of JS in your pages:

```
$('a[href="/"]').off();
```

[jQuery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) Remove an event handler, **.off()** with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements.

Your code will works! Just use the correct xHtml:

```
<td><a href="/">Home</a></td>
```

or, to remain in the same folder

```
 <td><a href="./">Home</a></td>
```

If you have **www.yoursite.com/ciao/#apage** href="./" will return **www.yoursite.com/ciao/** while href="/" will return **www.yoursite.com**

Comment: what is meaning of - ./ ?

Comment: If you have **www.yoursite.com/ciao/#apage** href="./" will return **www.yoursite.com/ciao/** while  href="/" will return **www.yoursite.com**

Comment: @Michael  Did you tested?

Comment: @Michael add this code in after all your script prease **$('a[href="/"]').off();** and let me know. See the last edited answer for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to include an `input` element as first child of `body` element, with `tabindex` set to `1` ; using `history.replaceState()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
#abc {
  position: relative;
  top: 800px;
}
  </style>
  <script>
  function home(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.replaceState({}, "home", location.pathname);
    document.getElementById("home").focus()
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input tabindex="1" type="button" id="home" style="opacity:0;width:0;height:0" />
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="#abc">abc</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="abc"><a href="" target="_self" onclick="home(event)">Home</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/sRyoc4uR2N4F8sbzD4zZ?p=preview